# How is Messages traffic routed?

Tags: messages

AppleID signed in to MacOS message for the first time: `are SMS messages to cell phones routed through the iPhone?`  Assume the recipient is not using an Apple device (not use iMessage).

`If I did not have an iPhone, would I be confined to sending messages to AppleIDs (email addresses)?`

If any additional context is needed to confine a proper question please ask in comments.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to question 1, it depends. Some carriers allow WiFi calling on other devices (you can check by going to `FaceTime` > `Preferences` > `Calls from iPhone` checkbox). If WiFi calling is being used, your Mac sends it over the internet to the cell carrier. If it's not, then it's sent through your phone (I'm not sure if it's sent over the LAN or through Apple's servers to the iPhone, but I think it's the first).

Second question: correct, you'd only be able to send iMessages to AppleIDs.

Hope this clarifies your questions.

Comment: If iPhone WiFi calling is engaged, is the message routed from `Mac -> iPhone -> internet (wifi) -> carrier` OR `Mac -> internet (wifi) -> carrier`?

Comment: @gatorback The second one: `Mac -> Internet -> carrier`. To be honest though, I'm not sure whether they go through app first, so it might be `Mac -> Internet -> Apple -> carrier`.